# Using The Same Name For A Table As A Schema

Tags: sql

To put it simply, will bad things happen if I use a table name which is also a schema name.

For example:

Aircraft.Aircraft

Comment: That's fine. The `AdventureWorks` example database has `Person.Person`

Comment: Thanks @Martin, that's interesting - which version is that? mine has Person.Contact perhaps they changed it because they thought it was a bad idea.  Im using AdventureWorks 2008R2...

Comment: `AdventureWorks2008` [This link confirms it was renamed but says nothing about why](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlserversamples/thread/675d02ec-e4e6-4726-878e-0f49f03e4a9b)

Comment: Yeah, not sure what is happening there, I also found this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/4dca3ee8-ab02-447d-abf9-d0b90d85e605/)

Comment: @Martin, looks like its a case of having to enable filestream to get the person.person table.  But anyway it looks as though it has been renamed person.person FROM person.contact so I guess it wasn't an issue naming it person.person.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No reason why you can't do this, as far as I know, though you may confuse yourself later. I suppose things might get sticky if you wrote queries that didn't explicitly state the schema, but if you avoided doing that then you ought to be OK.

Having said that, I'd question the wisdom of doing this - to me, it suggests that either the schema name or the table name isn't properly describing what it contains.

Comment: Understood, I have a bunch of tables under the aircraft schema, like FlightLogs, Aircraft Types etc.  But for the aircraft table itself I cant think of a better table name than aircraft.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it will cause a problem, but I don't see why you would want to do that. You should name your schema something more descriptive of what you are modeling. For example, rather than naming your schema "Aircraft" name it "Airport" or "Air_traffic" or whatever.